# MagTek -- uDynamo (DUKPT)

Tags: java, android, encryption, credit-card

Has anyone been able to successfully decode the information from a MagTek uDynamo card reader on android?  I have the test application working correctly, but I need to be able to decode the card number.  It is DUKPT encryption.

It's for an internal school application with student ID's, so security is not a huge concern.

Thanks

Comment: hi, did you find the solution ?

Comment: No. I ended up being able to get the information I needed from the unencrypted fields. I never got the decryption to work properly though.

Comment: thanks for your response. Do you know where I can find these unencrypted fields ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's DUKPT Key management and TDES Encryption. If you really want to "roll your own" decryption routine you need to get your hands on the ANSI X9.24 standard. That will explain everything you need to know.